# Is it possible to host console application inside sharepoint web application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, console-application

I am having **.net console application**, and want to host it on **SharePoint 80 port**.

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: No, but you can have the console application on the server and trigger it from task scheduler if you wish. The console app can access SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can have the console application on the server and trigger it from task scheduler if you wish. The console app can access SharePoint.

[image]